# How to add the colormap to the matplotlib 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-gridspec

I want to add the colormap to show the gradient along x axis but unfortunately the whole figure turns black. I might be lacking something kindly help me in this. Here is the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Define the vertices of the rectangular rod
vertices = np.array([
    [0, -0.5, -0.5],
    [0, -0.5, 0.5],
    [0, 0.5, 0.5],
    [0, 0.5, -0.5],
    [10, -0.5, -0.5],
    [10, -0.5, 0.5],
    [10, 0.5, 0.5],
    [10, 0.5, -0.5]
])

# Define the faces of the rectangular rod
faces = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 7],
    [0, 1, 5, 4],
    [1, 2, 6, 5],
    [2, 3, 7, 6],
    [3, 0, 4, 7]
])

# Map the x-coordinate of each vertex to a color in the colormap
x = vertices[:, 0]
norm = plt.Normalize(x.min(), x.max())
colors = cm.gnuplot(norm(x))

# Create a Poly3DCollection object with the vertices, faces, and colors
rect = Poly3DCollection(vertices[faces], alpha=0.8, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='black')

# Add the rectangular rod to the plot
ax.add_collection3d(rect)

# Set the limits of the x, y, and z axes
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 1])

# Add labels to the axes
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

I have used gunplot colormapping methodto give the gradiant color to the 3d plot but nothing works.
Kindly suggest me how to proceed. If there is any other method using which i can create a gradiant with 6 colors that would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem here is that the number of entries in the `facecolors` argument has to match the number of faces, otherwise it looks like matplotlib falls back to picking out the first colour in the list - here, that's black.

The second problem is that you're trying to create a cuboid with just 6 faces, but then colour it with a smooth colourmap. The polygons in matplotlib can only be coloured with a single colour each. So you have to subdivide your cuboid.

Here's my attempt at fixing these two problems! I create a set of points between 0 and 10 and then create vertices at these x-positions. I also construct the array of x-positions directly from the faces, taking an average of the x-position of each of the four vertices making up each face.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Define the vertices of the rectangular rod
N_sub = 50  # Set higher for better resolution; lower for better performance!
vertices = np.concatenate([
    np.array([[x, -0.5, -0.5],
              [x, -0.5, 0.5],
              [x, 0.5, 0.5],
              [x, 0.5, -0.5]])
    for x in np.linspace(0, 10, N_sub + 1)], axis=0)

# Define the faces of the rectangular rod
offset = (N_sub) * 4
faces = np.concatenate([
    [[0, 1, 2, 3]],
    *[np.array([[3, 0, 4, 7],
                [0, 1, 5, 4],
                [1, 2, 6, 5],
                [2, 3, 7, 6]]) + 4 * x for x in range(0, N_sub)],
    [[0 + offset, 1 + offset, 2 + offset, 3 + offset]]
], axis=0)

# Map the x-coordinate of each face to a color in the colormap
x = np.array([np.mean([vertices[idx, 0] for idx in face]) for face in faces])
norm = plt.Normalize(x.min(), x.max())
cmap = plt.get_cmap("gnuplot")
colors = cmap(norm(x))

# Create a Poly3DCollection object with the vertices, faces, and colors
rect = Poly3DCollection(vertices[faces], alpha=0.8, facecolors=colors)

# Add the rectangular rod to the plot
ax.add_collection3d(rect)

# Set the limits of the x, y, and z axes
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])
ax.set_zlim([-1, 1])

# Add labels to the axes
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps! I'm not sure I'm able to replicate the black edges however. I tried doing a second cuboid, like your original one, with six faces and `facecolor="none"` but this threw an error.

PS: I saved you an import by using `plt.get_cmap`.

Comment: Thats great!. It has solved the pupose. Thank you so much. But there is small doubt, when i try to extend the same graph to some bigger value of lets say x=1000 keeping all other parameter same. The graph gets shrunk in x direction but I want it to get extended along x so that i can bind a horizontal scrollbar to it. As I need to add some more plots on the surface along x direction. So it will not be visible if it gets shrunk. I request you to suggest me how to achieve that. I tred `set_box_aspect` method but it doesn't work for me. I have also tried adjusting fig size but nothing works.